# Solr (4.4+) solrconfig.xml location when creating cores

Tags: solr

I'm Trying to setup a multi core solr server for our webapplication but i'm having trouble creating new core through the coreadmin service.

I'm using Solr-4.4 because 4.3 ran into problems persisting the cores in solr.xml (datadir wasn't preserved) So i'm using the new Solr.xml configuration [4.4 and beyond](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solr.xml%204.4%20and%20beyond)

My solr.xml currently looks like:

```
<solr>
  <str name="coreRootDirectory">default-instance/cores/</str>
</solr>
```

solrconfig.xml is located at (solrhome)/default-instance/conf/solrconfig.xml

When trying to create a core with the url

```
http:/example.org/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=test-name&schema=schema-test.xml&loadOnStartup=false
```

gives me the error:

> Error CREATEing SolrCore 'test-name': Unable to create core: test-name
>   Caused by: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or
>   'default-instance/cores/test-name/conf/', cwd=/var/lib/tomcat7

The following seems to work:

```
http:/example.org/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=test-name&schema=schema-test.xml&loadOnStartup=false&config=/absolute/file/path/to/solrconfig.xml
```

The problem is this only seems to work with a absolute path (or possibly a relative path from /var/lib/tomcat7) which is not a workable solution.

What i'm looking for is a way to place  solrconfig.xml so it can be used to create new cores with that config (or a way the create those cores with the current location).

More or less the same will be needed for schemas

Answer (score 10):

This worked. Ran on command line and was viewable in admin console:

**solr create -c (name for core or collection)**

See README.txt for more info.

Comment: This is only available on Solr 5

Comment: we should be aware also that the command should be executed as the `solr` user

Answer (score 4):

In my case I took advantage of the [Core Discovery](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Core%20Discovery%20%284.4%20and%20beyond%29) feature in 4.4+, rather than creating the core using the management web interface.

This simply involved copying the example `collection1` folder from the `examples` directory (which I usually use as a starting point).

Then I had to make sure that there is core.properties in the root of my new core with `name=<new core name>` inside. Solr automatically detected the new core and allowed me to use it without any fuss.

This avoided the trouble of having to copying `solrconfig.xml` and `schema.xml` into any special location.

Comment: is it possible to do this on SolrCloud too? or we need to add the new core to the other nodes in the cloud one by one?

Comment: Don't know. I have since started using ElasticSearch.

Comment: @mydoghasworms  I used this approach and it worked for me.. thanks.

Comment: @Joe, I have since switched to Elasticsearch for my indexing and searching needs. I am just a casual user and I don't have very complex, high-volume use-cases, and the configuration overhead of Solr has put me off. I like the zero-configuration aspect of Elasticsearch. Anyway, just some food for thought if you are in the same boat ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem: `solrconfig.xml` was not in the classpath. I solved it by copying my configuration file templates into the classpath.

So I took a look at `http://localhost:8983/solr/#/~java-properties` to see solrs classpath definition and then i copied the template solrconfig.xml and schema.xml into the folder `C:\servers\solr-4.4.0\example\resources`. Furthermore i copied all the stopwords stuff there...

This solution is not a fully satisfying, but it works. Adding another path to the classpath should work, too. I'm slightly astonished that no default configuration for new cores can be declared within `solr.xml`

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the new Config Sets for this use case.

If you place your schema.xml and solrconfig.xml (and other config files like stopwords etc.) in a directory `$SOLR_HOME/configsets/myConfig/conf`, you can create a new core with this config by calling:

http://solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=mycore&instanceDir=my_instance&configSet=myConfig

See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Config+Sets

But they are not available until Solr 4.8, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-4478